# Pipeline post build fails with error java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction

Tags: jenkins, post-build

I am completely new to groovy scripting.
I am trying to post the test execution results by reading from json file and post it into TM4J. I have added the plugin of Test Management For Jira in my jenkins.  In the post build actions we are adding Pas, Fail, Skip count as well. When I add my groovy script with existing code my post build fails with the following error.

```
Error when executing always post condition:
java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:523)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:499)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:486)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:410)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@24ef8456
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@36b5001e
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@2986b5fc
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@7a8f7ff7
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2d12b28b
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2d12b28b
```

Here is my post build code with pass/fail/skip included:

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
            def fileContents = readFile "${workSpace}/detailsAll.txt"
            AbstractmyAction myAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractmyAction.class)
            if (myAction != null) {
                 //* Get the pass, fail, skip and diff count jenkins rawBuild
                Do something
                 //* Get the info from file content
                Do something
                 //* Construct pass, fail skip and jenkins build info message.
                Do something
                 //* Get the ULR.
                Do something
                 //* Get the test run details.
                if (params.RunA) {
                    testRunDetails = "Somethingthing is" + params.ClassName + "\n"
                } else if (params.RunB) {
                    testRunDetails = "Some thing" + params.Groups + "\n"
                } else {
                    testRunDetails = "All" + "\n"
                }
                //* get triggered by details.
                Some more code
                  //* Construct message to display in slack.
                slackMessage = "${A}${B}${c}${d}${e}${f}${g}${h}${i}${j}${k}"
            }
   
   //* This is my code to publish the test results in TM4J automatically
   def publisttestResult = publishTestResults autoCreateTestCases: false, 
   filePath: 'tm4j_result.json', 
   format: 'Test Management for Jira Output Result For JUnit', 
   projectKey: 'HelloWorld', 
   serverAddress: 'https://somewebsite.com'
        }
        deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
   }
}
```

If I delete all the If Else conditions from script and just leave my code it works but if I add my coder after If Else conditions are done executing the code fails complaining about

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction
```

Please help.